# running my code using terminal Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, terminal, sublimetext3

I've watched tons of videos about how to use sublime text 3 I do what they say but it doesn't work. When i type "subl test.c" in terminal it opens up a a file called test.c in sublime text 3 when i use the command gcc -c test.c everything is fine too, but when I try to run the code using ./test it says bash: ./test: No such file or directory

Comment: `gcc test.c` will create a `a.out`. Don't create executables called `test`

Answer (score 1):

Bash says that there is no such file or directory because you haven't created a file called 'test'. You should specify an output filename, i.e. you should type `gcc test.c -o your_out_filename`. Then you may run your program using `./your_out_filename`. Without `-o` flag gcc will create a `a.out` by default, so your out_filename will be `a.out`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following command to create a file called `test`:

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

If you don't use the -o option (`gcc test.c`) your created file will be `a.out`.

The option `-c` of gcc only compiles your file and doesn't link it to a program which you can run. The result of the `-c` option is only an object file called `test.o`.

Therefore the easiest way is the one I have mentionend above (`-o` option).

Answer (score 0):

You have to run:

```
gcc -o output test.c
```

`output` is the file you have to do `./output` in terminal for it to execute